# How can I backup a MySQL database on AWS?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've been playing with AWS EC2 and really like it. There is **one drawback** though, the instance could **disappear** due to hardware failure or whatever reason. This happened to me in my first week of operation. I was wondering whether there are good solutions to **backup** a *MySQL* database so that **I don't lose** my customer credentials?

Comment: replication is all you need http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transfer mysql database directly from EC2 machine to S3bucket but you will consume more cost for bandwidth and storage. You go for a third party application (which is safe) to **backup** your mysql or any plugins. Because they compress your data & encrypt and then save in S3 storage. Also, you can enable snap shot and take snap shots for volumes (hard drives)

I suggest you to use 'StoreGrid' backup software to **backup** your mysql database in EC2 machine. check this following link to know more about Online Backup Service on Amazon EC2/S3  http://storegrid.vembu.com/online-backup/amazon-ec2-s3-cloud-online-backup.php

Check this following link to configure MySQL database BACKUP http://storegrid.vembu.com/online-backup/mysql-backup.php?ct=1

Note: You have mentioned **Hardware failure** occurs often ! --- you can **backup** entire hard drives too using the above software.

I hope, now your MySQL data base is backed up from EC2 instance and stored in S3 storage safely.

Cheers !

Comment: You could also look at https://totalcloud.io to periodically create AMIs so that you don't have to shut down your instance.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon now offers Relational Database Storage, that is, pre-configured EC2 instances, without any OS access to host MySQL (or Oracle, or T-SQL for real) for you, but aim to solve much of the availability, reliability and durability issues one faces when trying to host transactional data store yourself on a bare EC2 instance.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

"automated backups, DB snapshots, automatic host replacement, and Multi-AZ deployments"

Comment: but it's more expensive :(